# Посчитать кол-во заказов по годам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица Employees с данными о продавцах и таблица Orders с информации о заказах.
Нужно посчитать кол-во заказов по годам.

Никак не могу сделать, сортировку по годам.

````
select CONCAT(e.lastname,' ',e.firstname) as 'Seller', 
COUNT(*) as 'Amount', YEAR(orderdate) as [year]
from Sales.Orders o
    join HR.Employees e
        on o.empid = e.empid
group by [year]```
````

Comment: А разве в выражении `group by` можно использовать псевдонимы столбцов? В Oracle точно нельзя. попробуйте `group by YEAR(orderdate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь, в `group by` нужно включить все поля, которые выводится без агрегатных функций. А для сортировки применить `order by`:

```
select CONCAT(e.lastname,' ',e.firstname) as 'Seller', 
       COUNT(*) as 'Amount', YEAR(o.orderdate) as [year]
from Sales.Orders o
     join HR.Employees e on o.empid = e.empid
group by e.lastname,e.firstname,YEAR(o.orderdate)
order by YEAR(o.orderdate)
```